# How to send a sms from unix server

Tags: web-services, unix, sms, sendmessage

My query is,per day i will get approximately 500 mails from the unix server. some sort of mails are very critical and these critical mails are need to send to some mobile numbers.
Is there any plug-in need to install in unix server like "sendmail" to send a mail to desired people???
If so could any one please guide me where i need to download or get such kind of plug-in's.

I got a option while browsing through internet but it doesn't works. It is

**echo "text-message" | mailx -s "test" @yourcarrier.(net/com)**

"text-message" : message body

"test" : subject of message

My mobile carrier is Airtel and it belongs to chennai circle : 919840number@airtelchennai.com

number@airtelchennai.com

above both options i tried but i didn't receive any sms to my mobile.

Your help will be very useful for me...!!!

Regards,
Sreeni.

Comment: Since sending SMS is not free, you probably have to register at a commercial provider of such a service, I guess. So -- is your question: Who provides such a service and how can I use it?

Comment: Hi John,Thanks for your quick response.Yes it is also one of my question. do you know if any of such service providers in india to give  this type of service and i want to configure this type of service in my server directly to trigger sms from server rather than from my mail box.

Comment: Cant we do like triggering a sms once you get mail? Then this requirement can be made as a independent one from server.

Comment: Hi Mari,Thanks for your response.Yes it is also a possible solution for me.can you please tell me the way how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Buy a GSM serial modem. For example [Siemens MC35i](http://www.smsco.it/en/modem/siemens_mc35i.jsp) is good choice. The you can issue modem AT commands to send SMS. Or alternatively there's [Gammu](http://wammu.eu/gammu/) cmdline tool which you can use for sending messages. Gammu also support various GSM USB dongles. Finally order SIM with plan dedicated to sending SMS, to get best price.

Comment: This is not suitable for many situations where the colo is overseas. It would make quite a bill.